# How to use cocoapods to install alamofire into watchOS app

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire, apple-watch

Here's my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project


target 'raceQs' do
 platform :ios, '11.1'
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for raceQs
  pod 'AppCenter'
pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'raceQs WatchKit Extension' do
  platform :watchos, '4.1'
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for raceQs WatchKit Extension
pod 'Alamofire'
end
```

I'm opening my project's xcworkspace and getting a compile error:

```
Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/raceQs-cwycjawfwoosfubowtoymeizvfln/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/raceQs.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/raceQs-cwycjawfwoosfubowtoymeizvfln/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/raceQs.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
```

In my Xcode project Navigator, the Frameworks/ Pods_raceQs_WatchKit_Extension is displayed in red.

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.